# Windows 2008 R2 Task Scheduler fails to execute commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008-r2

On my Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, a batch file is scheduled to run using Task Scheduler. For some reason, only a portion of the commands in the batch file are executed; Some commands are ignored.

Batch file looks like this:

```
cd s:
cd "S:\Reports\"
sqlcmd -S ipAddress -U login -P password -d dbname -i "S:\query.sql" -o "S:\Folder\Report.txt"
copy /A /Y "S:\Folder\Report.txt" Y:\
```

When I run the batch file by double-clicking on it, everything runs as intended; But when it is executed from task scheduler, only the `sqlcmd` portion runs correctly. The `copy` command does not seem to run. Even when I replace `copy` command with `xcopy` or `mkdir` or any other command, it does not run.

Even if I change the order of commands in the batch file, the commands do not run. But when the batch file is executed by double-clicking, everything runs perfectly.

The `Y:\` is a mapped drive under the same login. After typing my question this far, I went back and ran one more test. Interestingly, if I replace mapped drive with local drive, everything seems to be working okay. So, at this point it looks like mapped drive is the problem. Any ideas on resolving this?

Essentially, how to copy or move files to a mapped drive (different machine) using batch file executed from **Task Scheduler**?

Comment: 1. It's not `MS-DOS` actually :-) 2. replace `cd s:` with `s:` to switch drives 3. The first two lines aren't needed at all

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll try

Comment: @wOxxOm Nope, did not work. Still the same result. Copy to a different local folder works, but not remote folder.

Comment: Actually, the issue is different and most probably is related to the user account specified in the task properties or maybe the task is run before logon at `system startup`. Also, there's no need to add `I'll try comments`, it's not skype or some chat.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm running the job in Task Scheduler while logged into the machine. So, I do not believe `system startup` has anything to do with it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and that info? And maybe some screenshots of your task config. BTW I think this might be better answered on superuser.com. The things is, there's no problem with the code per se. It's a task scheduler config issue.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think so too, it is something to do with Task Scheduler and its configuration. May be it has something that 'Restricts' external interaction. What is Superuser.com? I'll check it out.

Comment: @wOxxOm Cross posted this question to superuser.com [here](http://superuser.com/questions/993722/mapped-drive-is-not-accessible-to-copy-files-using-task-scheduler)

Comment: Just FYI: There's absolutely no reason for the `copy` at all. You could change the `-o "S:\Folder\Report.txt"` to `-o "Y:\Report.txt"` in your call to `sqlcmd` and omit the copy completely.

Comment: Simply add `pause` at the end of the batch script to view any error messages...

Comment: Adding `pause` won't help because you won't be able to see the command window. @ToC, are `S:` and/or `Y:` mapped network drives? If so, they probably don't exist in the context of your scheduled task, in which case you should use the full UNC paths instead (`\\server\share`).

Comment: This is an issue with how you have the task configured. It cannot access the mapped network drives unless the task us configured to run only when the user is logged in. Use UNC paths instead and set the username and password for the task run as.

Comment: @briantist Thank you !! Thank you !! It worked. UNC path worked. Is there a way to upvote your comment?

Comment: Good news @ToC I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S:` and `Y:` are probably mapped network drives, but those are mapped in the context of a user session. The scheduled task will be run in its own session and won't have those drives mapped.

You should use the UNC path of the share instead (`\\server\share`) as that should work in either context (as long as the share is accessible to the user the scheduled task is running as).